# How to use movement for classical music with Apple Music?

Tags: itunes, apple-music

Apple Music groups tracks in classical music albums by work and movement, which is great. Here's an example:

[image]

When I add albums to my library, however, the grouping is lost. Here is how that same album appears in my library:

[image]

---

According to this [MacWorld article](https://www.macworld.com/article/3121662/software-entertainment/how-to-better-organize-classical-music-in-itunes.html) it is possible to edit the tracks to specify that they include work and movement grouping, however, this requires that one input the information manually, which is tedious and should be unnecessary considering that information is clearly there in Apple Music.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to preserve this grouping when adding classical music albums to iTunes from Apple Music?

Answer (score 1):

Only the tedious method. It is especially inconvenient on iOS. I use the Cesium player on iOS to better sort by Genre and Composer.